# Why is UART w/DMA only receiving last byte of sended data?

Tags: stm32, stm32f4discovery, stm32f4

[image: This is a screenshot of debug session]
This is the `UARTEx_RxEventCallback()` function which should continue to receive bytes. Here you can see in **Hercules** screen, I sent `123456789` but it only receives the last byte. Why is it happening. My DMA settings are set Normal (not Circular), Periph to Memory, Byte. NVIC interrupt checkbox is enabled. Everything is set as it should be.

[image: Task Init for DMA UART]
This is the my main task.

Comment: Please post your code as text and not as images. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/413337

Comment: In first image, code does not matter. You must look on right side of screenshot. It's the important part of my question. There are actual no code releated question here!

Answer (score 1):

Your DMA is not working because of the initialization order, you have to initialize DMA before the UART/USART, like this:

```
/* Initialize all configured peripherals */
MX_GPIO_Init();
MX_DMA_Init();
MX_USART3_UART_Init();
```

Comment: OMG, THANK YOU!!! I have been struggling to figure out why DMA simply doesn't work for days (different boards, STM32 variants, etc.). CubeMX generates the Init() calls in the wrong order!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't increment memory address, so data always copied to the first element of the array. *hdma_usart3_rx.Init.MemInc* should be *DMA_MINC_ENABLE*

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: I do increment the memory address: `hdma_usart3_rx.Init.MemInc = DMA_MINC_ENABLE;`